# Spacing around parentheses in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've recently had some problems getting a path working properly.  The solution turned out to be simple but I had an unexpected problem that stopped me getting to it.  The following line, included in an erb template, works perfectly:

```
<%= button_to "Confirm delivery", delivery_confirm_path( @delivery ) %>
```

This one doesn't:

```
<%= button_to "Confirm delivery", delivery_confirm_path ( @delivery ) %>
```

It seems spacing before the opening parenthesis is not allowed in this case.  The error I get is this:

```
/app/views/deliveries/_delivery_buttons.html.erb:22: syntax error,
unexpected tLPAREN_ARG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...ivery", delivery_confirm_path ( @delivery ) );@output_buffer...
...                               ^
```

Can anybody explain why this causes an error?

EDIT: for info, this is Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.9, on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: http://www.justskins.com/forums/ruby-1-8-space-122361.html

Comment: Seems like a limitation of the language. You found a workaround, I don't see why you had to put it as a question.

Comment: @Gazler +1, excellent link with a post by Matz himself!

Comment: Simply because I hadn't realised it was a limitation of the language - I was thinking it must be getting confused with the button_to function call, or something within the erb innards I can see in the error message.  I pretty much never put a space before a parenthesis like this so I've not noticed this limitation in a few months working with Ruby, but I spend all day working with people who do spacing that way, so to my eyes it didn't look like an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anyone that puts a space before a parameter-list parentheses gets what they deserve, I say!

The problem is that it's closing out the call to `button_to` in the second example (space before the parentheses) and doesn't know what to do next.

Comment: In your comment to Sebastien's answer, you mention it is documented when you can use a space.  Do you have any link to it?  Gazler's comment links to a pretty definitive answer from Matz, but I've not seen where it is documented that spacing is important.

Comment: @asc99c I was referring to the O'Reilly book The Ruby Programming Language, section 2.1.6.2, "Spaces and method invocations". The general rule: don't put a space before a method and its opening paren :) It doesn't speak in the book to why, and provides a different breaking example.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is how ruby's parser actually works, but I think of it this way: The comma before `delivery_confirm_path` has higher precedence than the parentheses, unless you get rid of the space.

The parser sees the method call as this:

```
button_to "Confirm delivery", delivery_confirm_path
```

In other words, `delivery_confirm_path` is parsed as a method call without arguments. But then the parser sees the dangling `( @delivery )` and it's not valid syntax because it follows the `button_to` method call. It's as though you had this invalid syntax:

```
button_to("Confirm delivery", delivery_confirm_path) ( @delivery )
```

You can avoid the comma-precedence by doing this instead:

```
button_to "Confirm delivery", (delivery_confirm_path ( @delivery ))
```

But it's usually easier to just remove the space.

The principle to remember is that if there's a space before parentheses with a method call, the parentheses are used as grouping, and not as method-call parentheses.

Here are some examples to help. I use the following method in my examples:

```
def foo(*args); puts args.inspect; true; end
```

If you're on ruby 1.9, I suggest turning on warnings when running the examples: `$-w = true`. This will display `warning: (...) interpreted as grouped expression` if you have space before parentheses.

These two lines are syntactically equivalent:

```
foo (1)
foo 1
```

That's because `(1)` as a grouped expression is just `1`.

What good is grouping?

One reason is just for more readability. You might consider it easier to understand with parens in this expression versus without:

```
foo (2 + 3)
foo 2 + 3
```

Another reasons is precedence. Let's say I have a low-precedence operation, like the `and` operator. Because the method call has higher precedence, the `and` is evaluated after the call. This prints `[2]` and returns `3`:

```
foo 2 and 3  # same as foo(2) and 3, i.e. true and 3
```

But this prints `[3]` and returns `true`:

```
foo (2 and 3)  # the grouped expr returns 3, which is passed to foo
```

Note, however that the `and` example is somewhat contrived, because ruby doesn't allow removal of the preceding space. (I'm not sure why, since `&&` is allowed instead of `and`.) But you get the idea.

```
foo(2 and 3)  # syntax error - but why?? I still don't understand.
foo(2 && 3)   # works fine. This is strangely inconsistent.
```

This demonstrates that removing the space before a method call will elevate the method-call precedence above a comma:

```
foo 1, foo 2  # syntax error; the 2 is dangling
foo 1, foo(2)  # ok
```

Another gotcha is argument lists.

```
foo 2, 3  # both are treated as args to the method call
foo (2, 3)  # syntax error, because "2, 3" is grouped as an expression, but is not a valid one
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use a space between a function and its arguments. In fact, in rails the parser engine wants the parenthesis of the function just after its call.
That's the rails' life.

Hope to help you.

Thank you

Comment: This is not correct; the *circumstances* under which you can, and cannot, use a space, is documented. `puts ("hi")`, for example, works fine.

Comment: You **can** use a space between a function and its arguments, in Ruby, and so in Rails too. These all produce the same output:

`puts "hi"`
`puts ("hi")`
`puts("hi")`
`puts"hi"`

Comment: The examples above only work with a single argument since it is equivuilent to `puts(("hi"))`. `puts ("hi", "bye")` is a syntax error.