# Strange activity with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, error-handling, syntax-error

I have created a small app with Ruby on Rails, and testing the app output three errors. However, these errors seem irregular. For instance, each of the errors asks me to insert a parenthesis where one is not needed in the line of the source code file at all. This is the set of errors:

```
         1) Error:
 StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about:
 SyntaxError: C:/Sites/sample_app/app/views/static_pages/about.html.erb:1:      syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
 ...putBuffer.new; provide (:title, "About")
 ...                               ^
 C:/Sites/sample_app/app/views/static_pages/about.html.erb:1: syntax error,    unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
 ....new; provide (:title, "About")
 ...                               ^
 test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:17:in `block in   <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'


         2) Error:
 StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help:
 SyntaxError: C:/Sites/sample_app/app/views/static_pages/help.html.erb:1:    syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
 ...putBuffer.new; provide (:title, "Help")
 ...                               ^
 C:/Sites/sample_app/app/views/static_pages/help.html.erb:1: syntax error,   unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
 ...r.new; provide (:title, "Help")
 ...                               ^
 test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'


         3) Error:
 StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
 SyntaxError: C:/Sites/sample_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:1:   syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
 ...putBuffer.new; provide (:title, "Home")
 ...                               ^
 C:/Sites/sample_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:1: syntax error,    unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
 ...r.new; provide (:title, "Home")
 ...                               ^
 test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in   <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

How can I correct this in the program, if it is needed? Is it even something on my side of the program?

Comment: Please show your controller and view code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When framing a question, it's important to come up with a title that is indicative of the subject of the question. "Strange activity with Ruby on Rails" tells us nothing. Please edit your question and come up with a title that better reflects what your question is about. The error mentioned is a syntax error in your code. We can't help you debug your code, especially syntax errors, if you don't show us what you wrote, except to say "there's a syntax error", which you could have figured out by reading the message. Please read and follow "[ask]".

Answer (score 3):

Try `provide(:title, 'About')`. ie, no space after `provide`

Comment: It worked. There are now no errors in the test. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ran into the same trouble, thanks for the tip. Really sucks that the error message is so cryptic. More precise explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675093/spacing-around-parentheses-in-ruby